# Why wasn't Jiraiya burried in the Konoha Cemetery?

Tags: naruto, boruto

In Boruto episode 136, I noticed that Jiraiya's tomb is in the woods and not in Konoha Cemetery. Jiraiya is a leaf ninja so I assume his remains should be in Konoha cemetery and in fact he died because he was trying to save the village. The place doesn't also resemble [Mount Myōboku](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Mount_My%C5%8Dboku).

[image]

Comment: Didn't watch Boruto, but... is that an actual grave, or more of a memorial? If I recall correctly, Jiraiya's body fell into the ocean and was not retrieved.

Comment: [This answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/622/49) has a passage from chapter 520 that confirms Jiraiya's body was unrecoverable as of the events of the 4th War — dunno, again, if circumstances have changed in Boruto.

Comment: Great. Never thought it could be a memorial though, I cant remember though if Jiraiya's body drop in the ocean. I'm not reading Naruto manga also. But, if his body is unrecoverable, any thoughts why his memorial is in this forest? Any significance to him?

Comment: No idea, no: that's why I left comments instead of an answer here :)

Comment: Could it be the place where Jiraya trained Naruto in the early days? I still remember some old naruto episodes where Jiraya trained naruto under such forest and provided holy talks around some old hay hut.

Answer (score 1):

As JNat stated in the comments, this is a memorial for [Jiraiya](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Jiraiya) rather than an actual grave. Jiraiya's body was unrecoverable at the bottom of the sea, so there was no body to bury in the cemetery.

But given Jiraiya's importance and status, why *wasn't* he given a proper funeral?
Well, Naruto built this memorial outside the village shortly after Pain's Assault. This is likely due to the fact that during Pain's Assault, Konoha had just been destroyed and time to hold a funeral was not a luxury they had.

Comment: +1 for the idea that Konoha was not completely rebuild yet thus it might be the reason why Jiraiya was not given a proper funeral. But I am more interested "why that place", or "what is that place" for Jiraiya or Naruto why his memorial was placed there.

Answer (score 0):

Jiraiya's body was killed in the water, he was thrown into the water at the time of his death, and the sight was too deep to find his body. It was Naruto who made him a statue in the woods just outside the Leaf Village